# Smoothing/fixing a list in Python conditionally

Tags: python, list

I'm working on smoothing out a list of integers in Python. I know how to fish out unique items in the list, but I am a little lost at how to smooth a list based on a certain condition.

Let's say I have strings that comprises of only `0`s, `1`s and `2`s. My aim is to detect contiguous `1`s (1 or more continuous `1`s), and remove them if and only if the flanking numbers are identical. I am able to write a simple for loop that corrects singularly occurring `1`s, like:

- `00100` can be fixed, so that it becomes `00<0>00` (corrected digit flanked by `<>` for clarity).
- `00122` will not be fixed, because the flanking numbers `00` and `22` are different. So is `00120`, for example.

I can simply use the following logic to "fix" by looking at the 2 digits before and after the `1`:

```py
# Example string
string = '000010000'
_string = list(string)

# For loop
# Skipping the first 2 and last 2...
# because there is insufficient information
for i in range(2, len(string)-2):

    # Store the 2 digits before and after
    flanking = string[i-2:i] + string[i+1:i+3]

    # If flanking contains one unique value...
    # then we can fix it
    if len(set(flanking)) == 1:
      _string[i] = flanking[0]

print(string)            # Original string
print(''.join(_string))  # "Fixed" string
```

However, I run into a mind block when attempting to do the same, for **contiguous** `1`s:

- `0011111100` should be fixed so that it reads `00<000000>00` (again, `<>` added only for clarity to show the replaced digits)
- `0011111122` should not be fixed, since the digits around the contiguous `111111` are not identical `00` vs `22`.

Note: the string is not a float/integer—it is a list of "calls" created from biological data, and I have the intention to "smooth" it out (for the lack of a better word).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution using regular expressions and `re.sub` with a replacement function (wrapped in a loop to test cases):

```
import re

for s in ["2211111122","001111100","001111122"]:
    print(re.sub(r"([02-9])(1+)\1",lambda m: "{0}<{1}>{0}".format(m.group(1),"0"*len(m.group(2))),s))
```

result:

```
22<000000>22
00<00000>00
001111122
```

Replacement occurs for 2 first strings, but not for the last one, because the flanking numbers are different.

How it works: It just looks for 1s wrapped but 1 digit different from 1 (the same left & right, using `\1` reference), and calls a function which replaces the group of 1s by a group of 0s of exactly the same length (with the `<>` wrapping. If you don't need it, replace `"{0}<{1}>{0}"` by `"{0}{1}{0}"`).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'll give it a go :) and get back to you ASAP. p/s: I don't need the `<>` in there, it's just shown in my example to better illustrate the "fixed" digits :)

Comment: you're welcome. For once, replying with regexes doesn't end with downvotes :)

Comment: I've made some changes to your regex pattern, because I wanted it to do the following (1) replace the `1`s with the digits that flank it (so it can be 0 or 2, depends on what group is matched) and (2) allowing two digits before/after the contiguous `1`s. The updated regex, based on yours, is as follow: `print(re.sub(r"([02])\1(1+)\1\1",lambda m: "{0}{0}<{1}>{0}{0}".format(m.group(1),m.group(1)*len(m.group(2))),s))` ;)

Comment: I'm glad you appropriated the regex for yourself. I won't sue you, glad it helped :)

Comment: Your regex is still the real magic tho :) I'm sorry if I didn't describe my use case in greater detail, but what you have there is perfect. Thanks again!